# Problem running PHP in a Django app with Apache

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, apache

I have a web app running in Django which mainly consists of HTML and JavaScript (which is running with no issues) but recently a colleague created some additional content that is implemented PHP. The web page is served by Apache which is configured to accept .-h- files which it executes correctly. The problem I’m seeing is that there is an HTML file that generates a form with a few fields and a submit button which has the PHP file as it’s action like this:

```
<form id=“form1” action=“generator.php” method=“post”>
  .
  .
  .
  <input type=“submit” name=“submit” value=“Generate”>
</form>
```

The .php file can be simplified as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=“Content-Type” content=“text/html”; charset=utf-8” />
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    echo “Generating”
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When the submit (Generate) button is pressed, the network debugging window in the browser shows that generator.php is indeed loaded but the echo statement isn’t executed.

The PHP part of the application is non-negotiable much to my chagrin. If there needs to be more information please let me know.

Comment: Django does not render PHP code, so you can not use `render(request, 'my-php-file.php')`, or at least not directly. I would also strongly advise not to mix the two. Why use Django if you want to render this with a PHP engine?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don’t want to mix the two, unfortunately I’m kind of stuck with the code that was written by someone else. I’m going to make a  strong case for taking a different approach.